# Response error in wcf c# API

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

My code written in c# wcf service. which call the third party payment API.

```
string requestBody = "{ \"cardToken\":\"xxxxx\", \"expiryDate\":\"xxxx\",\"cvv\":\"xxx\",\"amount\":\"xxx\" }";                        
string data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody);                        
var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage responseDebitAPI = client.PostAsync("http://example.com/example/api/payments/debit?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", content).Result;
```

After call the API I got the below error:

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Tue, 20 Jun 2017 08:04:59 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 1011
  Content-Language: en
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}}
```

Please help me in above code if I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this and let me know the results:

```
string requestBody = "{ \"cardToken\":\"xxxxx\", \"expiryDate\":\"xxxx\",\"cvv\":\"xxx\",\"amount\":\"xxx\" }";                        
string data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(requestBody);                        
var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

HttpResponseMessage responseDebitAPI = client.PostAsync("http://example.com/example/api/payments/debit?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", content).Result;
```

you are serializing input three times!! that's the problem.